# Finding data attribute and checkbox children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope you can see what I'm trying to do here.
I am trying to keep the same structure for the divs but clicking the select all in the top area only selects those 3 and the bottom select all only selects the bottom 3.

Obviously there are better ways to do this but I have stripped my code back to this basic example. 
please help me rewrite this line:

`$("div").find("[data-profile-id='"+profileID+"']").find(".score_alert_cb1").each(function() {`

So i can use the profile-id data attribute to select the checkboxes that fall inside that div.

Thanks

```js
$('.profile #select_all_cb').click(function() {
  var profileID = $(this).closest('.profile').data('profile-id');
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("div").find("[data-profile-id='"+profileID+"']").find(".score_alert_cb1").each(function() {
          $(this).prop('checked', true);
      });
  } else {
      $("div").find("[data-profile-id='"+profileID+"']").find(".score_alert_cb1").each(function() { //Check all boxes
          $(this).prop('checked', false);
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile" data-profile-id="1">
   <div>
      A lot of data before my checkbox
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="select_all_cb">select all
    </div>
    <div>
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
    </div>
 </div>
 <br /><br />
 <div class="profile" data-profile-id="2">
   <div>
      A lot of data before my checkbox
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="select_all_cb">select all
    </div>
    <div>
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are unique, so changed `id="select_all_cb"` to `class="select_all_cb"`.

On click `.select_all_cb`, goes up and finds `.profile` parent, store the checkbox value as boolean in `isChecked` variable, and finds all `.score_alert_cb1` checkboxes within the current `.profile` element.

```js
$(".profile .select_all_cb").click(function() {
  var profile = $(this).closest(".profile");
  // var profileID = profile.data('profile-id');
  var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
  profile.find(".score_alert_cb1").prop("checked", isChecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile" data-profile-id="1">
   <div>
      A lot of data before my checkbox
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="select_all_cb">select all
    </div>
    <div>
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
    </div>
 </div>
 <br /><br />
 <div class="profile" data-profile-id="2">
   <div>
      A lot of data before my checkbox
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="select_all_cb">select all
    </div>
    <div>
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
       <input type="checkbox" class="score_alert_cb1">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just changed this line to save some time `profile.find(".score_alert_cb1").prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));`

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
$("div").find("[data-profile-id='"+profileID+"']").find("[type=checkbox]")each(...}
```

?

Comment: In the "a lot of data before my checkbox" there will be more irrelevant checkboxes. Thanks

Comment: Ah, okay.  What's wrong with the original approach then?  I mean, you mention "better ways to do this", but what's the issue you're encountering with your current approach?